# Post AngularJS model to complex model in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to create a model in JavaScript and post it to an ASP.NET MVC controller method via $http.post. When inspecting the JSON that's posted, my `Address` properties are populated. However, when the ASP.NET MVC controller is hit, all the corresponding Address properties are null.

Angular controller method:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
    alert("Form is valid!");

    var member = {
        TempCardNumber: $scope.tcardno,
        Title: $scope.title,
        FirstName: $scope.firstName,
        LastName: $scope.lastName,
        Address: [
            {
                AddressLine1: $scope.address1,
                AddressLine2: $scope.address2,
                AddressLine3: $scope.address3,
                AddressLine4: $scope.address4,
                TownCity: $scope.towncity,
                County: $scope.county,
                PostCode: $scope.postcode,
                PhoneNumber: $scope.phone
            }
        ],
        EmailAddress: $scope.email
    };

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/Index',
        data: member
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
}
```

Posted JSON:

```
{"TempCardNumber":"633341677489986320","Title":"Mr","FirstName":"test","LastName":"user","Address":[{"AddressLine1":"8 Eaton Close","AddressLine2":" Hatton","TownCity":" Derby","County":" Derbyshire","PostCode":" DE65 5ED","PhoneNumber":"01234567890"}],"EmailAddress":"test@gmail.com"}
```

ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult Index([FromBody]MemberModel model)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

I've tried stringify-ing the JSON, passing it in as just `data: member` in my Angular post, and using `[FromBody]` on the ASP.NET MVC method but always, the `model.Address` properties are null.

Is there anyway I can do this without posting each property to my ASP.NET MVC controller?

Edit: Added MemberModel POCO for clarity

```
// MemberModel class
public string Title {get;set;}
public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}
public Address Address{get;set;}
public string TempCardNumber {get;set;}
public string Email {get;set;}

// Address POCO 
public string AddressLine1 {get;set;}
public string AddressLine2 {get;set;}
public string AddressLine3 {get;set;}
public string AddressLine4 {get;set;}
public string TownCity {get;set;}
public string County {get;set;}
public string Postcode {get;set;}
public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
```

Comment: `BindModel` should be around somewhere... If in your POST event on the server side, it should bind based on the Model of the input type, if not then  the object is not able to cast properly.. Canyou show us your Class model `MemberModel` ?

Comment: Do you not need to set the content type somewhere, in order to tell ASP.NET MVC that you are posting JSON? Try adding `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }` to your `$http` request.

Comment: MemberModel class added

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using the `[HttpPost]` attribute on your controller method

Comment: he has already said his Controller is being hit so i doubt this is the issue. But happy to be wrong.

Comment: Yes, the controller is being hit - I have the [HttpPost] attribute on it

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Try passing the object into JSON.stringify() and use that as your data value